# Fragment Page Adapter - Only call Get Item once

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have tabs setup in my app. I'm using list view fragments that each do a call to pull down data.

Something like the following:

```
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0: 
                return FirstFragment.newInstance();
            case 1: 
                return FirstFragment.newInstance();
            case 2: 
                return SecondFragment.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
```

It's working great, however I don't want the call to happen every time the tab is visited, only the first time.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: are you using a ViewPager?

Comment: yes, it's living in my activity_main.xml

Comment: by default, one fragment offscreen is always retained. You can change this value with setOffscreenPageLimit

Comment: So I'd just want to change that number to the total number of tabs I have?         viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

Comment: if you want to be called just once for each fragment, yes

Comment: The problem I think I'm seeing with this approach is that it fires the call now for each tab, even before its been clicked. I want the data for each tab to be loaded on demand, not upfront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always instantiate those fragments somewhere in your constructor and then just pass a reference to it in `getView(...)`.

Here's an illustration:

```
public class YourPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    YourFragment fragment1, fragment2, fragment3;

    public YourPagerAdapter() {
        fragment1 = YourFragment.newInstance();
        fragment2 = YourFragment.newInstance();
        fragment3 = YourFragment.newInstance();
        ...
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: 
            return fragment1;
        case 1: 
            return fragment2;
        case 2: 
            return fragment3;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

That way, your fragments would only got instantiated once - when you're creating your adapter.

Better yet, wrap those fragments in a `List`. That way you could simplify your `getItem(int position)` to just `return mFragments.get(position)`.